# Падеж числительного, управляемого словом "достаточно''

Tags: грамотная-речь

Привожу отрывок из текста на русском научном  сайте:

*Раньше парусные суда имели маленькую осадку, и семь футов под килем наверное было достаточно для безопасного плавания.*

Вопрос: а не ошибка ли падежная форма "семь футов" и не должно ли быть "семи  футов" в этом предложении?

Answer (score 1):

***Конечно ошибка!*** Правильно *"семи футов".* Достаточно чего? Конечно же, нельзя задать вопрос ни именительного, ни винительного падежа "что?", только *родительного.*

Answer (score 1):

Думается мне, что предложение взято вот [отсюда](http://seafarers.com.ua/under-keel-clearance/6237/).

> Раньше парусные суда имели маленькую осадку, и семь футов под килем наверное было достаточно для безопасного плавания. А давайте вместе посчитаем, достаточно ли 7 футов под килем в наше время?

Правильное написание (семи футов [Р. п.]; обособление запятыми вводного слова "наверное"):
*Раньше парусные суда имели маленькую осадку, и семи футов под килем, наверное, было достаточно для безопасного плавания.*

Наречие [*достаточно*](http://endic.ru/kuzhecov/Dostatochno-5453.html) в этом контексте действительно требует родительного падежа (кого? чего?):
*В доме **всего*** [было] *достаточно. Нам* [было] *достаточно своих **яблок**. **Ко́рма** для животных* [было] *достаточно.*

К счастью, **бензина** в баке было достаточно, и мы выбрались. [Василий Аксенов. Круглые сутки нон-стоп // «Новый Мир», 1976]
**Хулиганья** среди послевоенных школьников было достаточно. [Сергей Довлатов. Чемодан (1986)]

**Дополнение**
У глагола [желать](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) управление и родительным падежом, и винительным (при конкретизации), поэтому все абсолютно правильно во фразеологизме.
[Желать, желаю] (чего?) *Попутного ветра и* (что?) *семь футов под килем.*

[Достаточно одной таблетки](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJ3z-0kWg6I)

Answer (score 0):

Теймураз, так язык не изучить! Его знает только вузовская филологическая профессура, простым смертным, русскоязычным притом, его не постичь.

[«Попутного ветра и семь футов под килем»](http://www.fps-nn.ru/parusnaja-shkola-20148/-7-futov-pod-kilem/); [наркомовские 100 грамм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_100_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC)...

**Семь футов под килем** из морского пожелания стало идиомой, как и **сто грамм** (но не граммов) **для храбрости**.

Ваш научный сайт, видимо, не посмел посягнуть на фразеологию, но так как он (сайт) ещё и вводное забыл обособить, нет ему веры, хоть он дерись. (Он - сайт - научен в других сферах, не в языковых.)

---

"Достаточно" у нас отдыхает, работает "без":

*Я и без семи футов под килем доплыву.*